# HTTP Request Header Authentication and user role update

Tags: geoserver

I'm using the authentication filter HTTP Request Header Authentication in my server. The problem is when I update a user role, the authentication filter doesn't know that I did an update. In this way, I need to save a Security Authentication settings in the GeoServer Portal to make the authentication filter know that it had an update.

For instance:

The user `guest` has access to the layer `layerabc`:

request: `curl -v -u secret:guest -G "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/workspace/wms?request=GetMap&layers=workspace:layerabc&bbox=-10478599.333558243,5136568.300763845,-10473707.363747992,5141460.270574097&width=256&height=256&srs=EPSG%3A3857&format=application%2Fvnd.mapbox-vector-tile&TILECOL=1954&TILEROW=3045"`

response: `Status 200 OK`

If I remove the `guest` access to layer `layerabc`, I'll keep receiving `Status 200 OK` until I go to the GeoServer Portal > Authentication Menu > Click Save.

Is there a way to make the authentication filter know automatically that I have updated a user role?